# How do I fix this depression in my concrete patio?

Tags: concrete

I have a concrete patio with a 4-foot by 2-foot shallow oval area that retains water.  The concrete is sort of a knockdown pattern (see photo). How do I resolve this depression without smoothing it over and making it slippery?
 How do I level the area and make the pattern match the surrounding area?

[image: patio]

Comment: You're going to have to add material and "smooth it over" to make the surface level, then add a top coat of the same material/style to match the rest.  So I guess your question is really "how to I level the surface and then match the surrounding area".

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - what sort of material?

Answer (score 2):

Is this a drain strip?

[image]

If so it may be possible to cut some shallow grooves in the patio concrete decking to conduct the standing water in the depression over to the drain strip.

[image]

It would obviously be your choice but this may look better overall than a smoothed on patch or filler. Such grooves could be cut by someone experienced with using a portable power grinder with a thin cutoff type blade.

Comment: Yes, that is a drain strip.

Comment: The area where the water puddles has been worn down over time so the area has many dimples that collect dirt. I had recently bleached it to get it clean.